# Enabling annotation processing workspace-wide in Eclipse w/o maven

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, workspace, processor

I had a really hard time searching for the answer and couldn't find any, here is my current situation:
(Running Eclipse 3.5 Galileo with JDK1.6.31)

I am trying to set-up Annotation Processing inside my workspace(s), the aim is to activate annotation processing workspace-wide as we have 20+ Projects and setting everything up each time we create a new one is annoying and dangerous in case we forget to do it ( and generating almost 100 new configuration files ).

According to Java 6 API adding the Jar containing annotation processors to the classpath should automatically make them avaible in the compiling process.

So I though adding it to a project and making it availble to export would work, but it doesn't.

I am aware of the fact that Eclipse uses its own compiler but it is supposed to behave the same way (or isn't it).

Is there any possibility to pass arguments to the JDT compiler?
Or some setting I haven't heard of inside Eclipse?